# Recuperar Data do tipo Date - php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Olá, eu to buscando do banco uma informação de data num grid com várias informações, estou fazendo assim:

```
 $data = $tbdeliberacoes->getData();
 date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data));
```

e este é o meu retorno na tela:

```
 31/12/1969
```

para todos os campos ele mostra essa data. Mas as datas gravadas no banco estão normais.

O campo que quero buscar é do tipo Date.

Comment: Quando vc imprime `$data` ela vem em qual formato?

Comment: a variavel $data é impressa d/m/Y

Comment: Se `$data = $tbdeliberacoes->getData();` já retorna em `d/m/Y` não precisa do date nem do strtotime.

Comment: Não entendi bem a questão. Está retornando todos os dados corretos, apenas as datas aparecem repetidas? Se sim, não é falta de incrementar a iteração com os resultados, como por exemplo com o uso do foreach ?

Comment: Sim, o campo no banco é do tipo DATE, eu busco a data em um arquivo "json" do symfony. Neste eu coloco date('d/m/Y', strtotime($tbdeliberacoes->getData())), no action eu coloco:

list($dia, $mes, $ano) = explode("/", $request->getParameter($field));
                        $data = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($ano."-".$mes."-".$dia)); $arrQuery[] = 'upper(data) LIKE \'%'. strtoupper($data) . '%\'';

Se eu habilitar o modo de debug eu recebo este erro: Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string
Se eu desabilitar o modo debug todas as datas aparecem como: 31/12/1969

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` só vai converter a data em timestamp se ela estiver no formato YYYY-MM-DD.

Se $data já está no formato d/m/Y, então a chamada a `date` é desnecessária.

Para entender melhor sobre conversão entre formatos de datas, veja este artigo: http://rberaldo.com.br/php-conversao-de-datas-formato-brasileiro-e-formato-iso/

Comment: E aí Beraldo ? Vazou do iMasters ?

Comment: Não. Apenas dou uma passada aqui de vez em quando.